# sharepoint continous crawl set to 1 minute

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have SharePoint 2016 Version. Right now we are running Default continous crawl every 15 minutes. so the result in the search Webpart atleast take 15 min but the Client wants to get Display with Maximum wait time 1 Minute. Setting continous crawl for 1 min will create heavy load in farm.

Is there any other alternate solution anyone have used ?.

Answer (score 2):

If you reduce the delay you should consider having dedicated servers for:

- Crawl target
- Crawler
- Content Processing (Can be shared with crawler role depending on size)

This will minimize the impact the crawls have for the end users. Keep the search servers as free as possible from other services that are used by the WFE servers.

Edit: The most sensible solution is to get them to ignore "instant" search results and explain to them that indexing DOES take some time. Also with a requirement like this make sure you have a recovery concept for your SSA, shich can only be rebuild properly from a SP-Farm backup (You can limit it to the SSA)

Edit for comment:

The servers mentioned are in order of priority. The crawl target will make the farm more responsive while having a dedicated server for crawling and/or content processing increases your crawl speeds. Don't try to sell a very low crawl freshness. If you have a requirement like this you should also monitor your freshness. Update the same list item once every minute and retrieve it via search and check the modified time in the result to check the freshness. Also monitor your cleanup crawls so they don't get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Atleast if not instant, waiting for a min or 2 min is ok. Waiting for indexing to complete (15 min) is not practical in this particular Client working Environment.